# I throw a pot of $10$ dice. What is the probability that I get at least two sixes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, dice

**Problem:** I throw a pot of $10$ dice. What is the probability that I get at least two sixes?

**My solution:** $1 - \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10} - \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^9 \cdot 10$. I got this by doing the following.

The probability of getting no six is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10}$.

The probability of getting exactly one six is $\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^9 \cdot 10$.

Hence, the probability that I get at least two sixes is $1 - \left(P[\text{no six}] + P[\text{exactly one six}]\right)$.

**Question:** Am I right?  This seems more efficient than figuring out the probability of getting two sixes, three sixes, and so on, and then adding up those probabilities.

Comment: the logic is good, but I don't get the arithmetic.  Where do you get $\frac 1{10}$ in the second term?

Comment: This is very nearly correct.  The probability of getting exactly one six however needs adjusting.

Comment: Typo.  I meant $1/6$, not $1/10$. Updated.  @lulu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very slightly wrong. The probability of getting exactly one six is actually $\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^9 \cdot 10$.

Answer (score 2):

We calculate this answer using the binomial distribution. The probability of getting $n$ sixes out of 10 is
$$
P(n)={10\choose n}
\left(1\over6\right)^n
\left(5\over6\right)^{10-n}
$$
so in this case the probability of zero or one sixes is
$$
\begin{align}
P(n <2)
&={10\choose 0}
\left(1\over6\right)^0
\left(5\over6\right)^{10}
+{10\choose 1}
\left(1\over6\right)^1
\left(5\over6\right)^{10-1}\\
&=
\left(5\over6\right)^{10}
+10
\left(1\over6\right)
\left(5\over6\right)^{9}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice.  I have not officially learned/taught myself about distributions yet, but I have heard of this one.  Did not think to apply it.